# How to cast to System.Timespan?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

can someone tell me how to cast System.Timespan? to System.Timespan
I keep getting this error when tryin to get the date difference between the current date and a date from a linq query (see belwo)

```
System.TimeSpan ts = i.joinDt - DateTime.Now.Date;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
System.TimeSpan ts = (i.joinDt - DateTime.Now.Date).Value;
```

Comment: I'd suggest `System.TimeSpan ts = i.joinDt.Value - DateTime.Now.Date;` to avoid converting `DateTime.Now.Date` to a nullable only to convert the result back again.

Answer (score 6):

To get a `TimeSpan` from a `TimeSpan?` you need to access the [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6.aspx) property of the nullable - no need to cast.

```
TimeSpan? tsn = i.joinDt - DateTime.Now.Date;
TimeSpan ts;
if(tsn.HasValue)
{
  ts = tsn.Value;
}
```

Or:

```
if(i.joinDt.HasValue)
{
  TimeSpan ts = i.joinDt.Value - DateTime.Now.Date;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> can someone tell me how to cast System.Timespan? to System.Timespan

You need to specify a default value for the case where the `TimeSpan?` is null:

```
TimeSpan? nullableTs = ...
TimeSpan ts = nullableTs ?? TimeSpan.Zero;
```